# How to handle duplicate DKIM selectors?

Tags: email, dkim, dmarc

### Background

When using third party tools which send mails from your domain, you often need to setup DKIM records with selectors defined by the third party.  E.g. for MailChimp you're asked to setup:

- k2._domainkey.example.com
- k3._domainkey.example.com

The selectors (`k2`/`k3`) must match those defined by the third party, in order to function as expected / match the selectors sent in the mail's headers.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29145283/361842), DKIM selectors must also be unique; i.e. you cannot have multiple public keys associated with the same DKIM selector (so whilst DNS would allow me to create 2 TXT records called `k2._domainkey.example.com`; that would lead to unexpected functionality; most likely intermittent mail failures.

However, there's no rule to ensure that the third parties provide unique selectors; or even standards to make collisions less likely (i.e. MailChimp don't suggest using `mailchimp1._domainkey.example.com` or anything like that); most examples of DKIM records I've seen have a 3 char selector (typically 2 characters and a number), giving only a few thousand unique selectors; so collisions are reasonably likely.

Note: I mention MailChimp above as that's a well known example mail provider; but this is a generic question, rather than specific to that provider.

### Question

What options are available when DKIM selector collisions occur?

Is it possible to satisfy both provider's requirements, or is that only possible where the providers have added functionality to allow you to specify your own selector value.

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @andi not so far. Only options are to contact the provider to see if they can give a different selector, or use different subdomains for each provider (meaning different 'from' addresses; each on the relevant subdomain), then map the multiple addresses to one mailbox if you want to receive mails on the sender's address too (or use a reply to address that's different to the sender's)

Comment: Thanks @JohnLBevan, that's easier said than done. For most of the (big) providers, it's hard to even reach e competent enough person to understand the problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

DKIM selectors are arbitrary strings. They're used to locate the corresponding public key on the DNS, and can virtually be anything that is valid as a DNS label.

Having said that, selectors provided by email providers usually have the provider name -- or something that resembles it -- so it is unlikely that there will be a clash. For example, Google Workspace's uses `google` as selector, and it would be very weird if another provider used the same selector. Obviously, if the provider gives you a way to change the DKIM selector, you can set it to anything, but then it is your choice.

Lastly, that answer you linked is wrong, or at least incomplete. From a strictly technical POV, DKIM allows multiple keys from a single selector:

> **6.1.2.  Get the Public Key**
>
> (...)
>
> 4. If the query for the public key returns multiple key records, the
>    Verifier can choose one of the key records or may cycle through the
>    key records(...)
>
> — [RFC 6376, section 6.1.2, item 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376.html#section-6.1.2)

It is just that selectors *in the DNS* cannot have multiple entries, due to a technical limitation. In theory, if another mechanism of storing DKIM selectors is used in the future, and if this mechanism supports multiple keys per selector, then DKIM will work just fine. The quote in that answer refers to unique selector *names*.

Comment: "It is just that selectors in the DNS cannot have multiple entries, due to a technical limitation. " How so exactly? `DKIM` are pseudo records, using `TXT` records, and you can completely have multiple `TXT` records on the same name.

Comment: "DKIM selectors are arbitrary strings. They're used to locate the corresponding public key on the DNS, and can virtually be anything that is valid as a DNS label" It goes even further than that since you can use dots, so `key1.google._domainkey`,`key2.mailchimp._domainkey`and so on. DNS is hierarchical and this allows it to be collision free.

Comment: Although you're right in that a DNS label can have many TXT records, for DMARC they're concatenated together to allow a larger record under a single selector. From RFC 6376, section 3.6.6.2: "Strings in a TXT RR MUST be concatenated together before use with no intervening whitespace. TXT RRs MUST be unique for a particular selector name; that is, if there are multiple records in an RRset, the results are undefined."